# Restoring and configuring ESX virtual images on Windows for test enviroment

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vmware-esx, vmware-server

I've got four virtual images back from our hosting provider, copies of the current live images. They are running on ESX, which I don't have available here.

I need to get these images running on a local server, and adjust the network configuration. VMServer 1.x and 2.x both declare the images as invalid, without providing anything specific. Sun VirtualBox was able to load and boot the disks, but had serious trouble with the network configuration: ifconfig allows me to configure eth2, while the active devices/connections, according to the Ubuntu systray network tool, are eth0 and etc1.

Is there something I can do to get these running on VMWare Server? We've got licenses for that. Or any ideas on how to get the network fixed on VirtualBox?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you have to use VMware Server? [VMware ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/products/esxi/) is free; you can download it and run it from a CD or a USB stick.

Comment: Thanks, that could work. Now I just need to figure out how to get ESXi running.